# cheetah templating with flask

Tags: python, flask, cheetah

I can't seem to find any information about using the [cheetah templating engine](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3) with [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask). Can anyone point me to something that google can't find, or show me how to use cheetah templates in a simple flask app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am no Cheetah or Flask expert, but I don't think you need any special support to make it work.  Looking at the examples for both, I came up with this (and it seems to work fine for me).

```
from flask import Flask
from Cheetah.Template import Template


mainTemplate = """
<html>
    <head><title>$title</title></head>
    <body><h1>$title</h1></body>
</html>"""


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main_route():
    return render(mainTemplate, {'title': 'Welcome to "/"!'})


def render(template, context):
    """Helper function to make template rendering less painful."""
    return str(Template(template, namespaces=[context]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Yep, you are right. Coming from some other frameworks, I thought there would be way more stuff involved (setting up some auto-render bit, etc.) This was very simple, and works great. Thanks a lot.